# Reading parquet files with pyarrow from windows shared drive

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, network-drive, apache-arrow

I'm trying to read parquet files which are located on a windows network drive using`pyarrow 6.0.0`.

The drive is mounted on my system so I can access the files under `H:\my\parquet\files`. The problem is that when I execute

`pq.read_table("H:\\my\\parquet\\files")`

the process just hangs forever. Python is not doing anything (no cpu or ram is used). I have to kill the python process manually.
This doesn't happen with files located on my local drive. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to solve this problem?